# How can create regular expression that allows white space but not newline line

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9$.\-_()]{0,98}[A-Za-z0-9$]`. I would like to allow white spaces but not new line character so \s doesn't work for me. I have tried option like putting a space etc and all of them also allow new line.

Comment: Please add an example of text that should match and an example of text that should not match.

Comment: "apple boy cat123" is the one where there is space but with "apple boy

Comment: if they are in different lines then I was to flag it out

Answer (score 0):

`[ \t]+` will match spaces and tabs.